# Image Pricing for Softlayer VM being captured as Image

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How the monthly price estimate should be calculated based on the size of the VM that is being imaged ? Any APIs for this available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to estimate this as the documentation [found here](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/introduction-image-templates) states that the VM being imaged will be compressed and follow a process for later provisioning, and even though image templates stablish a price per size ($0.25 per GB), they can´t be calculated previously because you can´t know the data amount and which kind of files are stored in the VM that will follow this process, for a similar case see [this link](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-estimate-the-average-file-size-savings-I-would-get-with-various-compression-tools).

Comment: Thanks. If that is the case then do we have SL API which will tell the used space on the VM ? We need the approximate cost so the disk size before compressing will also work.

Comment: Hello, I am afraid there is no api regarding this, this mostly because this information is not stored nor displayed by the portal.